# Is it possible to detect the type of key required when connecting to a wireless network?

Tags: wifi, wireless

So I was wondering if I could determine if a wireless network is asking for a specific type of key such as WEP/WPA ect? Or if it just takes the one you give it and processes that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible!

Almost any device that can wirelessly connect using WiFi, also has an interface for connecting to it right? I'm pretty sure that almost ALL devices, when prompted for a password say something like:

> "This network is using WPA2 Protection, please enter your password"

or:

> "This network is using an Enterprise Security, Please insert your USB Key"

etc.

In other words, the WiFi antenna broadcasts its SSID, your device picks up the SSID called "Network", the Antenna broadcasts the security information including it's MAC address, encryption algorithm, security type etc, which includes if it's "WPA" or "WEP".

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Pretty straight forward information provided by each wireless access point.

For instance in Android, this is what this information looks like in [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en):

[image]

Only the security types listed for an access point will be accepted.